# Python: Memory usage and optimization when modifying lists

Tags: python, optimization, memory, list, iteration

#### The problem

My concern is the following: I am storing a relativity large dataset in a classical python list and in order to process the data I must iterate over the list several times, perform some operations on the elements, and often pop an item out of the list.

It seems that deleting one item out of a Python list costs O(N) since Python has to copy all the items above the element at hand down one place. Furthermore, since the number of items to delete is approximately proportional to the number of elements in the list this results in an O(N^2) algorithm.

I am hoping to find a solution that is cost effective (time and memory-wise). I have studied what I could find on the internet and have summarized my different options below. Which one is the best candidate ?

#### Keeping a local index:

```
while processingdata:
    index = 0
    while index < len(somelist):
        item = somelist[index]
        dosomestuff(item)
        if somecondition(item):
            del somelist[index]
        else:
            index += 1
```

This is the original solution I came up with. Not only is this not very elegant, but I am hoping there is better way to do it that remains time and memory efficient.

#### Walking the list backwards:

```
while processingdata:
    for i in xrange(len(somelist) - 1, -1, -1):
        dosomestuff(item)
        if somecondition(somelist, i):
            somelist.pop(i)
```

This avoids incrementing an index variable but ultimately has the same cost as the original version. It also breaks the logic of dosomestuff(item) that wishes to process them in the same order as they appear in the original list.

#### Making a new list:

```
while processingdata:
    for i, item in enumerate(somelist):
        dosomestuff(item)
    newlist = []
    for item in somelist:
        if somecondition(item):
            newlist.append(item)
    somelist = newlist
    gc.collect()
```

This is a very naive strategy for eliminating elements from a list and requires lots of memory since an almost full copy of the list must be made.

#### Using list comprehensions:

```
while processingdata:
    for i, item in enumerate(somelist):
        dosomestuff(item)
    somelist[:] = [x for x in somelist if somecondition(x)]
```

This is very elegant but under-the-cover it walks the whole list one more time and must copy most of the elements in it. My intuition is that this operation probably costs more than the original del statement at least memory wise. Keep in mind that somelist can be huge and that any solution that will iterate through it only once per run will probably always win.

#### Using the filter function:

```
while processingdata:
    for i, item in enumerate(somelist):
        dosomestuff(item)
    somelist = filter(lambda x: not subtle_condition(x), somelist)
```

This also creates a new list occupying lots of RAM.

#### Using the itertools' filter function:

```
from itertools import ifilterfalse
while processingdata:
     for item in itertools.ifilterfalse(somecondtion, somelist):
         dosomestuff(item)
```

This version of the filter call does not create a new list but will not call dosomestuff on every item breaking the logic of the algorithm. I am including this example only for the purpose of creating an exhaustive list.

#### Moving items up the list while walking

```
while processingdata:
    index = 0
    for item in somelist:
        dosomestuff(item)
        if not somecondition(item):
            somelist[index] = item
            index += 1
    del somelist[index:]
```

This is a subtle method that seems cost effective. I think it will move each item (or the pointer to each item ?) exactly once resulting in an O(N) algorithm. Finally, I hope Python will be intelligent enough to resize the list at the end without allocating memory for a new copy of the list. Not sure though.

#### Abandoning Python lists:

```
class Doubly_Linked_List:
    def __init__(self):
        self.first = None
        self.last = None
        self.n = 0
    def __len__(self):
        return self.n
    def __iter__(self):
        return DLLIter(self)
    def iterator(self):
        return self.__iter__()
    def append(self, x):
        x = DLLElement(x)
        x.next = None
        if self.last is None:
            x.prev = None
            self.last = x
            self.first = x
            self.n = 1
        else:
            x.prev = self.last
            x.prev.next = x
            self.last = x
            self.n += 1

class DLLElement:
    def __init__(self, x):
    self.next = None
    self.data = x
    self.prev = None

class DLLIter:
    etc...
```

This type of object resembles a python list in a limited way. However, deletion of an element is guaranteed O(1). I would not like to go here since this would require massive amounts of code refactoring almost everywhere.

Comment: Where are the performance comparisons?

Comment: Also, note that whenever you feel the need to do a `xrange(len(somelist) - 1, -1, -1)`, you can also write it as `reversed(xrange(len(somelist)))`.

Answer (score 6):

Without knowing the specifics of what you're doing with this list, it's hard to know exactly what would be best in this case.  If your processing stage depends on the current index of the list element, this won't work, but if not, it appears you've left off the most Pythonic (and in many ways, easiest) approach: generators.

If all you're doing is iterating over each element, processing it in some way, then either including that element in the list or not, use a generator. Then you never need to store the entire iterable in memory.

```
def process_and_generate_data(source_iterable):
    for item in source_iterable:
        dosomestuff(item)
        if not somecondition(item):
            yield item
```

You would need to have a processing loop that dealt with persisting the processed iterable (writing it back to a file, or whatever), or if you have multiple processing stages you'd prefer to separate into different generators you could have your processing loop pass one generator to the next.

Answer (score 4):

From your description it sounds like a deque ("deck") would be exactly what you are looking for:

http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#deque-objects

"Iterate" across it by repeatedly calling pop() and then, if you want to keep the popped item in the deque, returning that item to the front with appendleft(item). To keep up with when you're done iterating and have seen everything in the deque, either put in a marker object like None that you watch for, or just ask for the deque's len() when you start a particular loop and use range() to pop() exactly that many items.

I believe you will find all of the operations you need are then O(1).

Comment: A simpler solution would be to pop out of the first deque and append into a *new* deque, which requires keeping track of less.

Answer (score 3):

Python stores only references to objects in the list - not the elements themselves. If you grow a list item by item, the list (that is the *list of references* to the objects) will grow one by one, eventually reaching the end of the excess memory that Python preallocated at the end of the list (of references!). It then copies the list (of references!) into a new larger place while your list elements stay at their old location. As your code visits all the elements in the old list anyway, copying the references to a new list by new_list[i]=old_list[i] will be nearly no burden at all. The only performance hint is to allocate all new elements at once instead of appending them (OTOH the Python docs say that amortized append is still O(1) as the number of excess elements grows with the list size). If you are lacking the place for the new list (of references) then I fear you are out of luck - any data structure that would evade the O(n) in-place insert/delete will likely be bigger than a simple array of 4- or 8-byte entries.

Answer (score 3):

A doubly linked list is worse than just reallocating the list. A Python list uses 5 words + one word per element. A doubly linked list will use 5 words per element. Even if you use a singly linked list, it's still going to be 4 words per element - a lot worse than the less than 2 words per element that rebuilding the list will take.

From memory usage perspective, moving items up the list and deleting the slack at the end is the best approach. Python will release the memory if the list gets less than half full. The question to ask yourself is, does it really matter. The list entries probably point to some data, unless you have lots of duplicate objects in the list, the memory used for the list is insignificant compared to the data. Given that, you might just as well just build a new list.

For building a new list, the approach you suggested is not that good. There's no apparent reason why you couldn't just go over the list once. Also, calling `gc.collect()` is unnecessary and actually harmful - the CPython reference counting will release the old list immediately anyway, and even the other garbage collectors are better off collecting when they hit memory pressure. So something like this will work:

```
while processingdata:
    retained = []
    for item in somelist:
        dosomething(item)
        if not somecondition(item):
            retained.append(item)
    somelist = retained
```

If you don't mind using side effects in list comprehensions, then the following is also an option:

```
def process_and_decide(item):
    dosomething(item)
    return not somecondition(item)

while processingdata:
    somelist = [item for item in somelist if process_and_decide(item)]
```

The inplace method can also be refactored so the mechanism and business logic are separated:

```
def inplace_filter(func, list_):
    pos = 0
    for item in list_:
        if func(item):
            list_[pos] = item
            pos += 1
    del list_[pos:]

while processingdata:
    inplace_filter(process_and_decide, somelist)
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not provide enough information I can find to answer this question really well. I don't know your use case well enough to tell you what data structures will get you the time complexities you want if you have to optimize for time. The typical solution is to build a new list rather than repeated deletions, but obviously this doubles(ish) memory usage.

If you have memory usage issues, you might want to abandon using in-memory Python constructs and go with an on-disk database. Many databases are available and [sqlite](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) ships with Python. Depending on your usage and how tight your memory requirements are, `array.array` or numpy might help you, but this is highly dependent on what you need to do. `array.array` will have all the same time complexities as `list` and numpy arrays sort of will but work in some different ways. Using lazy iterators (like generators and the stuff in the `itertools` module) can often reduce memory usage by a factor of n.

Using a database will improve time to delete items from arbitrary locations (though order will be lost if this is important). Using a `dict` will do the same, but potentially at high memory usage.

You can also consider [`blist`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/) as a drop-in replacement for a list that might get some of the compromises you want. I don't believe it will drastically increase memory usage, but it will change item removal to O(log n). This comes at the cost of making other operations more expensive, of course.

I would have to see testing to believe that the constant factor for memory use for your doubly linked list implementation would be less than the 2 that you get by simply creating a new list. I really doubt it.

You will have to share more about your problem class for a more concrete answer, I think, but the general advice is

- Iterate over a list building a new list as you go along (or using a generator to yield the items when you need them). If you actually need a list, this will have a memory factor of 2, which scales fine but doesn't help if you are short on memory period.
- If you are running out of memory, rather than microoptimization you probably want an on-disk database or to store your data in a file.

Answer (score 2):

Brandon Craig Rhodes suggests using a `collections.deque`, which can suit this problem: no additional memory is required for the operation and it is kept O(n). I do not know the total memory usage and how it compares to a list; it's worth noting that a deque has to store a lot more references and I would not be surprised if it isn't as memory intensive as using two lists. You would have to test or study it to know yourself.

If you were to use a deque, I would deploy it slightly differently than Rhodes suggests:

```
from collections import deque
d = deque(range(30))
n = deque()

print d

while True:
    try:
        item = d.popleft()
    except IndexError:
        break

    if item % 3 != 0:
        n.append(item)

print n
```

There is no significant memory difference doing it this way, but there's a lot less opportunity to flub up than mutating the same deque as you go.

Comment: I assume the "% 3" check is a placeholder to simulate the operation of  "somecondition()" from the original question, right?

Comment: @Oddthinking, Right, I was just applying some silly condition (numbers divisible by three are filtered out).

Comment: Overall I still don't like this solution much though. At best it helps your memory by a factor of 2, probably a lot less. If you're that hard-up for RAM, you should be moving your data onto disk. (And because you need all the nodes to keep references to either side in the `collections.deque`, I wouldn't be shocked if the RAM usage was actual higher, albeit less contiguous, than using lists.)